# Trying to Replace Integer value in Request json (for String using request.replace())

Tags: json, rest-assured

We are automating REST APIs using Rest assured where request json in which some of the attribute values needs to be replaced at run time, it can be String in some cases and Integer in other case.

request json:

```
{
 "bInfo":{
  "bEx":9, //Need to replace Integer value here
  "oriDate":"2020-07-08"    

},     

"education":{
  "educationE":{
      "proCal":9, //Need to replace Integer value here
      "cutAmt":250, //Need to replace Integer value here
      "totalAmt":20 //Need to replace Integer value here
  },
  "educationInfo":{
      "educationPur":"purtest", //Need to replace String value here
      "educationStr":"Mu",
      "educationPro":"RT",
      "rec":"N",
      "oriDate":"2019-08-10"
  } 
  },  
  "educationRes":{  
     "pTest": "", //Set String value here
     "rTest":"",
     "sFl":""
 },   

"educationRResult":{
   "as":""

}, 

 "qualities":[{

 "qualitiesE":{
 "gt":10, //Need to replace Integer value here
 "oValue":10,
 "pPr":10,
 "oVa":7,
 "cIn":1,
 "rRatio":2    
 }
  },
  {    
"qualitiesE":{
 "gt":1000,
 "oValue":10,
 "pPr":2,
 "oVa":5,
 "cIn":200,
 "rRatio":1
 }
  },
  {
  "qualitiesE":{
 "gt":70,
 "oValue":25,
 "pPr":100,
 "oVa":7,
 "cIn":40,
 "rRatio":5    
  }
  }]      
}
```

Code using to replace String:"dummyvalue"

---

```
request.replace("dummyvalue", "Test123");
```

O/P: Successfully working. Value replaced with Test123

Similarly in the same json needs to replace value with Integer: xyz value 50

```
request.replace works only with String, if want to replace as Integer value tried

Declared String value = "50" as String and Tried
```

Then it replaces as String value as "50" hence the the request when posted fails as the json payload expects the value as Integer 50. If try as below:

```
int amtIntValue = Integer.parseInt(50);

Then request.replace won't work
```

Please guide.
Attached the tried code.
[image: NullPointerException]

[image: Eductoin class]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using JsonObject in [gson](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/module-summary.html);

```
// Required imports
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
```

---

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    // request is the json in the OP converted to a String
    JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(request, JsonObject.class);

    // Update bEx in bInfo
    jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("bInfo").add("bEx", gson.toJsonTree(555));

    // Update proCal,cutAmt and totalAmt in educationE
    jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("education").getAsJsonObject("educationE").add("proCal", gson.toJsonTree(555));
    jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("education").getAsJsonObject("educationE").add("cutAmt", gson.toJsonTree(555));
    jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("education").getAsJsonObject("educationE").add("totalAmt", gson.toJsonTree(555));

    // Update educationPur in educationInfo
    jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("education").getAsJsonObject("educationInfo").add("educationPur", gson.toJsonTree("educationPur_updated"));

    // Update pTest in educationRes
    jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("educationRes").add("pTest", gson.toJsonTree("pTest_updated"));

    // Update gt in the first item of the qualities JsonArray
    JsonObject qualitiesE = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("qualities").get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    qualitiesE.get("qualitiesE").getAsJsonObject().add("gt", gson.toJsonTree(555));

    // Convert JsonObject back to String
    request = gson.toJson(jsonObject);

    System.out.println(request);
```

> Output; {"bInfo":{"bEx":555,"oriDate":"2020-07-08"},"education":{"educationE":{"proCal":555,"cutAmt":555,"totalAmt":555},"educationInfo":{"educationPur":"educationPur_updated","educationStr":"Mu","educationPro":"RT","rec":"N","oriDate":"2019-08-10"}},"educationRes":{"pTest":"pTest_updated","rTest":"","sFl":""},"educationRResult":{"as":""},"qualities":[{"qualitiesE":{"gt":555,"oValue":10,"pPr":10,"oVa":7,"cIn":1,"rRatio":2}},{"qualitiesE":{"gt":1000,"oValue":10,"pPr":2,"oVa":5,"cIn":200,"rRatio":1}},{"qualitiesE":{"gt":70,"oValue":25,"pPr":100,"oVa":7,"cIn":40,"rRatio":5}}]}

Comment: Thanks for valuable suggestions. I have updated the json payload, please have a look. It is actually nested/JSONArray inside JSONObject. I had missed this node to add to my question. Please guide as unable to solve my issue after using the given code (might be due to the Json wrong payload hierarchy)

Comment: Also, Thanks for editing question formatting, also if I use the above code, my value goes as 0 in place of 50. (Trying with "Test" : {       
      "amt":"value"), in place of 'amt' tried by reflecting the suggested code. Please guide in this as well.

Comment: I updated the answer according to the new json. Where exactly you want to update an Integer? And why do you want to update a String with a Integer?

Comment: Thanks for guiding, dummyvalue supposed to be Integer, it is not String.

Comment: You can update value of `InfoDetails` with an Integer (despite of the data type of existing value is String or Integer) using this suggested answer. And regarding the error you mentioned in comments(value goes as 0 in place of 50); I can't figure out a reason without checking the code.

Comment: @la1 - Can you update the OP with your approach, so other members can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with your code for the given example json, able to replace the Integer value to 50. However in my real scenario unable to succeed with my problem, My bad. I didn't give the correct json format, looks like due to it it is having issues with my real json Payload. Thanks a lot for your valuable help and guidance. I Accepted the answer,  Also I updated the my real json format in the question now, please look at it, if possible can help. Once again thanks a lot.

Comment: When I reflect the same code in my new json payload scenario, getting Null Pointer Exception at: // Get the valueDetails object as a JsonObject
JsonObject eductionObject = jsonObjectNew.getAsJsonObject("Education");//null pointer exception. If debugged, under child shows 'null' or nearest doesn't shows the

Comment: Your json is not valid again. (Not because of the comments). Please add a valid json which can be parsed. Before you put in the question, use online json validators (eg:- [jsonformatter.com](https://jsonformatter.org/)) to check the validity of the json.

Comment: Once again thanks for extending help, Updated the payload again after verifying the format on jsonformatter.com.

Comment: I updated the answer according to the new json. I could find a simple way to update the values without converting json to POJOs.

Comment: wow, excellent, this is what looks like I was searching for. Thanks a lot solving the issue such easy way. Able to successfully solve my issue with the provided answer, I wish could give double accepting the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Trying to create re-usable method from the above code, however facing NullPointerException. Raised other query, Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62250035/gson-tojsontreeintvalue-throws-null-pointer-exception-when-trying-to-pass-inte